# No data inserted to database

Tags: c#

It is hard to give this question a title. And not easy to explain the issue.

Basically I have a stored procedure which works when I test it manually.
And if I place the object property inside the IF block, it will work.

The following does NOT work:

```
    var dao = new CableDAO();
        foreach (var tag in tagsFromCustomer)
        {
            Log.Information("Tag ID: {0} - Class: {1}", tag.TagId, tag.Class);

            //if (tag.TagId== "PT215009D")
            //{
                try
                {
                    int returnValue = dao.UpdateCable(tag);
                    Log.Information("Executed update on: {0}. Return value: {1}", tag.TagId, returnValue);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(ex.Message);
                    Log.Error(ex.StackTrace);
                    throw;
                }
            //}
        }
```

And this WORKS:

```
    var dao = new CableDAO();
        foreach (var tag in tagsFromCustomer)
        {
            Log.Information("Tag ID: {0} - Class: {1}", tag.TagId, tag.Class);

            if (tag.TagId== "PT215009D")
            {
                try
                {
                    int returnValue = dao.UpdateCable(tag);
                    Log.Information("Executed update on: {0}. Return value: {1}", tag.TagId, returnValue);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(ex.Message);
                    Log.Error(ex.StackTrace);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

The data in the collection is the same in both examples. Meaning that the object with the TagId PT215009D does exist, so the UpdateCable runs with that object passed into it, regardless of the IF statement.
I can verify this by looking at the logs or during debug with breakpoints. Same object with same parameters.

But the weird thing is nothing gets updated in the database unless I test it in the IF-block.

The following is the code of my Data Access Object:

```
    public class CableDAO
{
    private readonly string connectionString;
    public CableDAO()
    {
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public int UpdateCable(Tag cable)
    {
        using (var dbConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            using (var command = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = Properties.Settings.Default.OracleProcedureNewCable;
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.BindByName = true;

                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_tag_id", Value = (object)cable.TagId ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_description", Value = (object)cable.Description ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_description_2", Value = (object)cable.Description2 ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_tag_category", Value = (object)cable.Class ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_cable_estimated_length", Value = (object)cable.CableEstimatedLength.Replace(".", ",") ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_discipline_code", Value = (object)cable.DisciplineCode ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_system", Value = (object)cable.FreeFunction ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_category_id", Value = (object)cable.CategoryId ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Double, ParameterName = "p_dry_weight", Value = (object)cable.DryWeight ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_location", Value = (object)cable.FreeLocation ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_to_area", Value = (object)cable.ToArea ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_from_area", Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cable.FromArea) ? DBNull.Value : (object)cable.FromArea });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_to_tag", Value = (object)cable.ToTag ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_from_tag", Value = (object)cable.FromTag ?? DBNull.Value });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_installed_length", Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cable.InstalledLength) ? DBNull.Value : (object)cable.InstalledLength.Replace(".", ",") });
                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterName = "p_segregation_level", Value = (object)cable.SegregationLevel ?? DBNull.Value });

                Log.Information("Parameters count: {0}", command.Parameters.Count);
                foreach (OracleParameter param in command.Parameters)
                {
                    Log.Information("Parametername: {0}, Value : {1}. Type: {2}.", param.ParameterName, param.Value.ToString(), param.DbType);
                }

                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dbConnection.Close();
                return rowsAffected;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of output/execution when nothing gets created in the database:
https://oimg.photobucket.com/albums/v48/differ/30-07-2020%2013-34-06.png

Screenshot of output/execution when the object gets created in the database:
https://oimg.photobucket.com/albums/v48/differ/30-07-2020%2013-31-24.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any exceptions without the `if`?

Comment: What data is in your collection? It's possible that your stored procedure is hitting some incorrect data or a fault and the error isn't being passed back to or trapped in C#.

Comment: Question: Is the row with the tag id equal to: PT215009D also not being updated without the IF?

Comment: @Alex, no exceptions

Comment: @ChrisBD, collection consists of objects of type Tag. The same data is being used, and in one example it works.

Comment: @PaulKaram, currently it is adding data to the database. I know the name of the method is misleading. No objects/rows with that ID exists prior these examples.

Comment: Look at the stored procedure logic. This cannot have anything to do with the presence or absence of an `if` block in your c#. You say it works manually but are you trying if for the data in all of the iterations? Are you setting the parameters exactly the same way they are being set in c#?

Comment: Can you retrieve the object with Id `PT215009D` from database then?

Comment: @Bemn, yes, after the code execution of the example with the IF-statement, i can see that the object has been added to the database.

Comment: @Crowcoder, when I tested it manually, I tested one at a time. And I tried my best to set the parameters exactly the same as they are being set in C#. Quite sure that the stored procedure is fine, and I indeed know it can't have anything to do with the IF-block. I am fully stuck here.

Comment: I don't know how to trace an Oracle database but if you are familiar with SQL Server Profiler I would use the Oracle equivalent to see exactly what commands and parameters are being used on the database.

Comment: Does every object have the same `TagId`? I would check the table definition to ensure that you're not passing a NULL value in where NULL is not allowed.

Comment: Most likely, one of the objects in the list has some bad or missing parameters.. I don't think there's anything else..
In order to debug it.. I suggest using the `if` block for each of the IDs until you hit a bump where it doesn't add, then you'd get the `Tag` with errors. Or, as others has stated, if there's any thing like the sql server profiler for oracle, use it and you'd know which data is missing

Comment: @ChrisBD, no. Every object has unique TagId. And I am sure that NULL is not passed in.

Comment: Does you log data give you any indications e.g. do you get a -1 returned by the `OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` ?

Comment: @ChrisBD, yes, I get -1 returned by both examples.

Comment: @PaulKaram, I just tested to use the IF block for each object. They are getting added to the database one after one as I tested them inside the IF. However, if i don't use the if-statement, the ExecuteNonQuery still runs, but nothing gets updated in the database, as I have mentioned.